# The issue about name that refer to current instantiation for partial specialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, language-lawyer

[temp.dep.type#1.4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.dep.type#1.4)

> A name refers to the current instantiation if it is
>
> > - in the definition of a partial specialization or a member of a partial specialization, the name of the class template followed by the template argument list of the partial specialization enclosed in <> (or an equivalent template alias specialization). **If the nth template parameter is a parameter pack, the nth template argument is a pack expansion whose pattern is the name of the parameter pack**.

Please note the emphasized part of the above bullet, Firstly, the **template parameter** here is not clear, Is it refer to the template parameter of the primary template or the partial specialization?

#### Example 1

If the template parameter refer to one of the primary template, then consider the following example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
template<typename...T>
struct Test{};

template<typename T>
struct Test<T>{  
  Test<T>* ptr;  // here is not a pack expansion
};
```

Is the `Test<T>` not a name that refer to current instantiation?

#### Example 2

If the template parameter refer to one of the partial specialization, then consider the following example:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct Test{};

template<typename...Args>
struct Test<void(*)(Args*...)>{
  Test<void(*)(Args*...)>* ptr;  // the pattern is Args*, not the name of parameter pack
};
```

Whether the `template parameter` refer to that of the primary template or the partial specialization, the form of corresponding `template-argument` seems do not satisfy the **emphasized part** of the bullet. However, In my understanding, `Test<T>` in example 1 and `Test<void(*)(Args*...)>` in example 2 all should be names that refer to current instantiation.

So, my question is:

1. which the template parameter in the bullet refer to?
2. Are these names  that refer to  current instantiation in two examples?
3. Is the emphasized part of the bullet a redundant sentence?

Comment: The entire bolded sentence looks rather badly worded and self-contradictory to me. I claim it is a defect and the sentence should be simply removed.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm  I think so.